# Is there a way to get the latest blocks from monero rpc

Tags: monerod, rpc

I'm looking at the documentation (https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html), I see there is a way to get the information of a single block, but I can't find the method to get the list.

The only way I can think of is:
- Get the latest block.
- With the "prev_hash" get the previous block, and get his "prev_hash" and look for the next one.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the getblocksbyheight, which is a binary call for speed. Or getblockheadersrange, getblockheaderbyheight. You get current height with get_info.